# Can control and data flow analysis be applied to other solution document?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am doing control flow and data flow analysis to my examle code. I am using instant analyzer (Analyzer with code fix - Nuget,VSIX)
My aim is analyze not only the code developer coding, also want to follow the data to the other classes.
Can i learn your thoughts about that ?
Thanks

Comment: EDIT : For example how like goto definiton, find all references diagnostics tool build ?

Comment: What specifically do you want to analyze?  You can get symbols for referenced code just like other symbols.

Comment: For example i want to follow a string variable where it come from, i want to go to other classes other methods, i want to do the flow analysis for all of them.

Comment: Then you need a decompiler, which Roslyn isn't.

Comment: I dont think so, because we can do it with stand-alone analyzer, there must be a way doing it in analyzer with code fix type.

Comment: Again, what specifically do you want to analyze?  Roslyn analyzers can only analyze control flow from source.  Whether or not it has a code fix makes no difference.

Comment: Think about a variable, i want to find where it has come from, which class ? which method ? I may come from an other document of solution. I want to learn about it.

Comment: Then use the DataFlow and SymbolFinder APIs.